# counting frog's jumps

Tags: combinatorics

n stones in a row, a frog is jumping from stone to stone **but never twice in the same direction** and visits each stone exactly once; In how many ways can this be done?

The frog starts from the first stone and finishes anywhere.

For example, if $p_n$ is the searched number, $p_3=1$, $p_4=2$, $p_5=5$ etc.

Comment: what's the 'searched number'? And the frog can jump to any of the $n$ stones from any stone, provided he hasn't been there before?

Comment: @snulty: Yes, he can.

Comment: You can probably find an answer by modifying what's here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation

Comment: Had a chance to look at that site yet?

Answer (score 1):

The are the "Euler or up/down numbers", see [here](https://oeis.org/A000111).